# Flutter SharedPreferences Future function returning two different states simulaneously

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await, sharedpreferences, future

```
Future<SharedPreferences> init() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  ...
  return prefs;
}
```

I have the above code to load the shared preference and do other processes (not related to shared preference) and then try to get them from Future builder:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => FutureBuilder(
      future: init()
      builder: (context, p) {
        if (p.hasData) {
          user = p.data.getString('user') ?? "";
          } else {
          user = "";
          print("No Preference Data");
        }
.....
```

The weird thing is that I get both user with a value but "No Preference Data" is printed. Any advice?

Note that even if I changed future: init() to future: SharedPreferences.getInstance() directly the same problem persists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error lies in the following line. Using paranthesis executes the function **without awaiting the output** and returns void. Later on when future completes it returns the user, thus, giving 2 different outputs. Update the code like this:

```dart
future: init(), //<-- Change this
future: init, // < To this, remove ()
```

It happens because `future:` expects a callback, so you either pass your function name directly ***if the parameters and return type match***:

```
future: _myFunction,
```

Or, you pass it an anonymous callback:

```
future: () => _myFunction(),
```